# Gradle problem when installing react-native on virtual device

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, gradle

When I'm trying to build react-native app on android I get following Error.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.ApplicationVariantImpl.
> Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

```
 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.
```